# Can I debug an iOS application over Bluetooth (or anything but USB?)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, bluetooth

I left my USB cable at home for a iPad mini, and I want to use XCode with it right now.

Is there any wireless way I can deploy and connect to the tablet without a physical USB cable?

Comment: It might be possible to run the application by building it with the provisioning profile for the device you want, putting the file into iTunes, and syncing it to the device.  It's a much longer process than running it normally and you won't be able to debug, though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc

Answer (score 0):

Wireless Device Support is no longer in current Xcode Versions.

What you can do is create an ad-hoc ".ipa" file build using ad-hoc distribution profile and wirelessly sync it to iPhone/iPad using iTunes.