# Xcode 9 hangs while trying to debug app over WIFI

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta

I have Xcode beta 3 and I am trying to debug over WIFI. I have followed all the steps mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383502/840520
I can see the device listed with a network icon even when its not connected by a cable, however when I try to run the app, it gets stuck at Signing the product and the Xcode hangs forever. My device has iOS 11 beta 2 installed on it.

I was not able to debug the app over WIFI even once.
Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, but in Xcode 9 beta 4. I realized that my iOS device was still running an outdated beta (either 1 or 2).

I updated it to iOS 11 beta 4 and then Xcode 9 reinstalled the debugging tools on it and everything works as expected now.

Comment: Thanks it was exactly the reason why it was not working! The wireless debugging works now with same level of beta on device and the Xcode. :)