# iPhone remote debugging over VPN connection

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, vpn

When my iPhone is on my local WiFi Xcode sees my iPhone over the network. My Mac Pro development machine is running macOS Server with a VPN server. When I VPN into my Mac Pro from my iPhone my Mac can ping the iPhone over its VPN IP address [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP43n.png) (172.22.0.225) and Network Utility is showing that port 62078 (the required port for debugging) is open. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1E7u.png) However, when I try to connect via IP in Xcode it says my iPhone is no longer available. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhY2s.png)
 Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am trying to achieve the same thing but it’s not detecting the device

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working on Mojave with OpenVPN and an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.4. I don't believe any special setup was necessary on the server side—I installed `openvpn` from `brew` and followed a few different configuration guides closely to setup a routed VPN (apparently the iPhone won't handle TAP, which is needed for an ethernet bridged VPN). I *did* install [tuntap](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/), but I think OpenVPN uses the default utun0 interface anyway, so it shouldn't matter.

Anyway, I did discover that this seemingly does not work if you are not on Wi-Fi. I discovered with Wireshark that although the iPhone will receive the message from Xcode when you are connected to the VPN server using cellular data, the iPhone seems to ignore the messages, sending `[RST, ACK]` packets back to the server. Maybe the iPhone is only listening for messages from Xcode on its `en0` interface, or maybe there is some check in place to ensure that the messages are not coming from one of its cellular data interfaces.  In any case, Xcode *can* see the iPhone when it is connected to the VPN server over Wi-Fi.

Unfortunately, I cannot confirm that this works with any other VPN servers, but I can at least confirm that remote debugging over a VPN is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had success just by following the standard OpenWRT "OpenVPN Server" guide (https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/server). I didn't need to follow any additional steps for routed VPN or bridging.

In Xcode, I needed to go to Window > Devices and Simulators, right click on my device, click "Connect with IP address" and enter the iPhone's IP address in the VPN subnet (192.168.8.2 in my case). Interestingly, I need to do that even when I am on my local WiFi so perhaps this step is not even needed in your case.

The iPhone needs a WiFi to be connected in order to allow wireless debugging. VPN has nothing to do with it. When on the go, I carry an extra (Android) device which I use as a hotspot in order to bypass this limitation. If you are at another place with WiFi I suppose this is not needed.

One caveat was that my Android device's Hotspot did not allow the iPhone to connect to the VPN for some reason. In order to work around this I first connect to the VPN over LTE and then connect to the hotspot.

A pleasant surprise was that apps that use Bonjour worked out of the box. Mothership devices were able to detect my remote iPhone and connect to it just fine. No WiFi trick was needed for this scenario.