# Xcode 11, with an iOS 10.3.3 device, there is no "Connect via Network" in Devices and Simulators dialog

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, remote-debugging, xcode11

Is there some reason that I won't be able to use "Connect via Network" in Xcode 11.2.1 to debug an iPhone 5c which has iOS 10.3.3 installed?

It works fine with my iPhone 7 Plus which has iOS 13.2.3. But with the iPhone 5c, there is no checkbox for "Connect via Network"

Both phones and the computer are connected to the same wifi, and all devices are logged in to the same Apple ID.

I am able to install and run apps to the iPhone 5c using the USB cable without any problems.

I also tried Xcode 10, and 9 with the same result.

iPhone 5c no checkbox
[image]

iPhone 7 Plus with checkbox
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul informed, the Network debugging requires Xcode 9.0 or later running on macOS 10.12.4 or later, and on the device, requires iOS 11.0 or later (64-bit device) or tvOS 11.0 or later. You can refer the following link for more details on this.

https://medium.com/sourleangchhean/how-to-do-wireless-debug-on-xcode-9-and-ios-11-c12a50f256c3#:~:text=Debug%20your%20app%20running%20on,or%20tvOS%2011.0%20or%20later.

[How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11, Apple TV 4K, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ6CWWTgqQE

Answer (score 0):

The network debugging feature requires 64 bit devices, so it will not work with the iPhone 5c.

Seems like the answer is pretty well covered here 
[How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11, Apple TV 4K, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc)